# WIndow CreateFile ReadFile WriteFile

Tags: c, api, winapi, createfile

I am a student so I apologize up front for not using the correct forum protocols. I am new to C, and *really* new to Win32 API.  My assignment is to write a small C program that copies the contents of an existing file to a new file, using only Win32 I/O system calls: CreateFile(), ReadFile(), WriteFile(), etc... File names are to be specified on the command line. Right now I'm just trying to get the basics functions in place, I will then focus on error handling. This code compiles, creates a new file, but the data does not get copied to it. Any advice? thanks for taking a look!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char buff[4096];
DWORD dwBytesRead, dwBytesWritten;
DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(buff);

//open source file and read it
HANDLE source;

// Create a handle for the source file
source=CreateFile(argv[1], GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

// Check for errors
if ( source == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ){
    printf("Error, source file not opened.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else printf("The source file is %s\n", argv[1]);

//create a new file
HANDLE target;
target = CreateFile(argv[2], GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if ( target == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ){
    printf("Error, target file not created.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else printf("The source file is %s\n", argv[2]);

//copy contents
ReadFile(source, buff, 4096, &dwBytesRead, NULL);
WriteFile(target, buff, dwBytesToWrite, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

//copy complete
CloseHandle(source);
CloseHandle(target);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: `FILE *target ` should be `HANDLE target;` That'd be the first thing I'd fix. The leaked file handle from `source` you lost with the second `CreateFile` would probably be the second. The rest of the undefined behavior in this code (`(DWORD)strlen(buff)` as an example) just add salt to the wound. Why not just call [`CopyFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: I caught that "HANDLE target" just as you replied, lol! I changed it but no data.

Comment: Google 'MSDN CopyFile'.

Comment: 'DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(buff); on an uninitialized array, to start with.

Comment: I am required to use only Win32 File Management API routines for low level file I/O (OpenFile, CreateFile, ReadFile, WriteFile, CloseFile)

Comment: ..then you get 'dwBytesRead' from the read call, telling you exactly how many bytes are in the buffer, but then, inexplicably, you decide to write 'dwBytesToWrite' to the output file.

Comment: STOP!  STEP AWAY FROM THE KEYBOARD!.  Don't write another line of code until you learn how to debug.  Software development is not 'get it to build, try it, when it does not work, post it on SO'.

Comment: You don't need dwBytesToWrite, as the write statement should be: | WriteFile(target, buff, dwBytesRead, &dwBytesWritten, NULL); | . You might also consider creating a loop that terminates when dwBytesRead == 0 after doing a ReadFile( ... ) .

Comment: Thank you so much  rcgldr, this worked. Finally making some progress!!!

Comment: @dana_mulse do you understand why what rcgldr says is correct? And why what Martin James says makes no sense?

Comment: @andlabs it made sense to me:)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in comments, your code has a few mistakes in it.  Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buff[4096];
    DWORD dwBytesRead, dwBytesWritten;

    // Open the source file
    HANDLE source = CreateFileA(argv[1], GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    // Check for error
    if (source == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Source file not opened. Error %u", GetLastError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("The source file is %s\n", argv[1]);

    // Create a new file
    HANDLE target = CreateFileA(argv[2], GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    // Check for error
    if (target == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Target file not created. Error %u", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(source);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("The target file is %s\n", argv[2]);

    // Copy contents
    bool ok = true;
    do {
        // Read file, check for error
        if (!ReadFile(source, buff, sizeof(buff), &dwBytesRead, NULL)) {
            printf("Source file not read from. Error %u", GetLastError());
            ok = false;
            break;
        }

        // Check for EOF reached
        if (dwBytesRead == 0) {
            break;
        }

        // Write file, check for error
        if (!WriteFile(target, buff, dwBytesRead, &dwBytesWritten, NULL)) {
            printf("Target file not written to. Error %u", GetLastError());
            ok = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    while (true);

    // Copy complete

    CloseHandle(source);
    CloseHandle(target);

    // Check for error
    if (!ok) {
        DeleteFileA(argv[2]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // all OK
    return 0;
}
```